# Python - Specify precise arguments in subclass method definition

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, warnings, variadic-functions

Is there any way in Python to specify a variable (unknown) number of arguments in a parent class method and the actual (real) arguments in its child classes without getting a warning? Here it goes an example to make me understand (I'm using Python 3.5):

```
import abc

class SuperClass(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def method(self, *args):

class SubClass1(SuperClass):
    def method(self, one, two, three):  # <-- I get a warning here
        # Stuff

class SubClass2(SuperClass):
    def method(self, *args):
        # Stuff
```

I cannot figure out how to make this code warning-free. Warning I'm getting is:

```
Signature of method 'SubClass1.method() does not match signature of base method in class 'SuperClass'
```

**Updated**

I'm getting the warning only in my IDE, Pycharm 4.5, caused by the inspection `Python->"Class must implement all abstract methods".`

Comment: The most important information is not that you got a warning, it says nothing. **The most important is a message you got, it describes what's wrong.** You should add that warning message to your question.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to attach the warning error :). Since I don't know how to update the question, I paste the comment here: `Signature of method 'SubClass1.method() does not match signature of base method in class 'SuperClass'`. Thanks @DawidFerenczy!

Comment: Thanks. You can update your question simple by clicking on `edit` link under the question :)

Comment: Aren't you missing a `pass` statement in  `SuperClass.method`? I don't get any warning using Python 3.5.0. Is that warning coming from Python command line or your IDE?

Comment: I also didn't get any warning with Python 3.4.3.

Comment: Yes, it's True, command line doesn't launch any warning. It's the IDE, Pycharm (v. 4.5), specifically one of the inspections: Python->"Class must implement all abstract methods".

Comment: @blazaid Oh, that's quite important information. You didn't mention that in your question at all. Could you add it there, please?

Answer (score 2):

You could try this instead in the subclass:

```
class SubClass1(SuperClass):
    def method(self, *args):
        try:
            one, two, three = args
        except ValueError:
            print('bad number of args')
```

That being said, this probably doesn't help if you're wanting code-completion functionality in your IDE.

Comment: The thing is I'm making a library and I don't want the users of the library to check the number of arguments each time they inherit from SuperClass. Yet thank you very much, I did not think of that solution and it's pretty cool :D.